# Replace Navchar (max) to Varchar(3000)? Migrate data from sql server to MariaDB Server using MYSQL workbench

Tags: sql-server, mariadb, mysql-python, migrate

I'm trying to migrate from ms sql server to MariaDB, using MySQL workbench There is a problem when Nvarchar(Max) is not compatible with MariaDB, the solution would be a script to change it to varchar(3000)?

I write this code but I'm not sure if exist a better method to do it.

```
import re

import re

input_file = 'MSSQLSERVER.sql'
output_file = 'MYSQL.sql'

with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    content = f.read()

content = re.sub(r'\[?nvarchar\]?\s*\(\s*max\s*\)', 'varchar(3000)', content, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(content)

    #python ReplaceNavcharMax.py
```

Comment: Do you realize that those are different data types and character encodings? `nchar` and `nvarchar` data types on SQL Server use UCS-2 encoding to support all of the code points on the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. `char` and `varchar` only support specific OEM code pages, unless you happen to use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I'm using UTF-8, is for esp language.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking in another solution, maybe it could work, I can do an Alter Table, and this sql code.
But the problem is "String or binary data would be truncated", I don't wanna lose data, so I'm still thinking of what to do.

```
DECLARE @schema_name NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @column_name NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @alter_sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    c.TABLE_NAME,
    c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE
    c.DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar'
    AND c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1;

OPEN column_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @column_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @alter_sql = N'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema_name + N'].[' + @table_name + N'] ALTER COLUMN [' + @column_name + N'] nvarchar(3000);';
    PRINT @alter_sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @alter_sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @column_name;
END;

CLOSE column_cursor;
DEALLOCATE column_cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

A max on [nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) indicates 2G which would correspond to a [LONGTEXT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/longtext/) in MariaDB.

Rather than trying to do the full conversion in python, MariaDB has a [sql_mode="MSSQL"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql_modemssql/). While this doesn't support `max`,  that should be an easy replace with sed/python/editor. Maybe if 3000 is the right size this can be changed before import.

Then you can import under `sql_mode="MSSSQL'` supporting some MSSQL syntax.

MariaDB will use the right encoding and collation for `nvarchar`.

ref: https://dbfiddle.uk/xtjujJUZ